# SQL Server : primary key auto increment - what about deleted rows and free key values?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm kind of new to SQL and databases and there's one thing that bothers me.

I'm using SQL Server for my ASP.NET MVC project and my database and its tables were auto-generated by Entity Framework using a code-first approach.

I have a table for book collections - just `CollectionId` and `Name` columns.
During development I've made many inserts and deletes in this table and right now it has 10 rows with `Id`'s 1 to 10 (the initial entries). But when I add a new one it has the `Id` set to 37. Obviously in the past there were entries with `Id` up to 36, but there are now gone and these numbers seem to be free.

Then why a new entry does not have the `Id` set to 11? Is it a kind of limitation or maybe a security feature?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20identity%20reuse

Comment: You should ***never ever*** "re-use" or "recycle" auto-generated values that have been used previously. Imagine having an audit table somewhere that tracks entities being created - how could you tell 6 months from now, which object the Id = 11 belongs to, if you *recycle* that Id when the first object that had is gets deleted, and you hand it out to a new, totally separate, totally independent object later on? Autogenerated ID - once issued - are done, gone, never to be reused again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior when we define identity column. Whenever we perform delete operations there will be gaps in records for identity column.

> Remarks from MSDN
>
> If an identity column exists for a table with frequent deletions, gaps can occur between identity values. If this is
> a concern, do not use the IDENTITY property. However, to ensure that
> no gaps have been created or to fill an existing gap, evaluate the
> existing identity values before explicitly entering one with SET
> IDENTITY_INSERT ON.

[IDENTITY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it also has to do with performance of the server.  The server typically cache's a group of ID's in memory to make assignment much faster, since the next number has to be stored on disk somewhere.  So if the server allocates 100 numbers at a time, it only has to write to disk 1 out of every 100 usages (inserts) of the identity.

Trying to maintain gaps in the sequence would suck up a lot of time.

If you create a new table, insert a single row, kill the server and restart, you'll find the next insert will most likely contain a gap of whatever that number of cached values contains.